# how to get top 100 results from google search using selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

webdriver.Chrome('/Users/name/PycharmProjects/untitled15/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml')
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('keywordtosearch')
search_box.submit()
time_sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

this is what so far I have obtained. I want to get top x searches from google for any given keyword

please assist me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar mini-project, where:

> to get results by their respective links:

```
results_list = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

> to simply loop through results and print them out:

```
i=0
for item in results_list:
    print (item.get_attribute('href'), '\n')
    if i == 10:
        break
    else:
        i+=1
```

Hope this helps! Good luck.